# Thesaurus for SQL Server full-text searching

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, full-text-search, thesaurus

Does anyone know where I can get a thesaurus (or list) of people's names and their relationships?

For example:

```
Bill = Billy = Billie = Will = Willie = William

Sue = Susie = Susan = Suzanne
```

I can build the needed xml file to become a thesaurus for SQL Server full-text searching. But I can't find a list of related people names anywhere.

Any help would be great!  Thanks!

Comment: I suppose you want it to be no-cost?